# How can I make a require_once header file in php to be used inside functions?

Tags: php

Can I set it as a global variable like:

```
<?php 

$GLOBALS['dbconnect'] = require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'/location/file.php');
$short = $GLOBALS['dbconnect'];

function someFunction() {
echo $short;
}

?>
```

I am using a database connection file twice, once outside of a function, and once inside a function. The query inside the function can't run because the credentials, servername, db, etc.. are not defined.

I'm not sure how this works?

When I place the require_once file inside the brackets, nothing happens, page is white.

This is the first example from link

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2(); 
?>
```

Comment: Use an atuoloader to auto load files. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: why can't I include it twice (as a simple solution?) is that because it literally says "require_once" ? And thanks for the new material, I was not aware of autoload.

Comment: Look at my example below, forget about OOP right now, I probably shouldn't have mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use an auto loader for whatever reason you can do the following. Have a file called `config.php` at the root of your project and have it contain this code.

```
<?php
// Replaced the \ which appear on localhost to / so it works online.
define("BASE_DIR", str_replace("\\", "/", __DIR__));

$files = [
    BASE_DIR . "/path/to/my/file.php"
];

function loadFiles() 
{
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        require_once $file;
    }
}
?>
```

Then in your other files include the `config` file and call `loadFiles`. This is essentially an autoloader but sometimes it can be hard to grasp so you can use this.

Comment: This is necessary? My problem is accessing a file from outside of a function inside a function. I can't change scope or something?

Comment: If you add the files you want to include within that array then you won't have to keep calling `require_once` or `include` over and over again. You can just call `loadFiles`.

Comment: thanks, I found a solution that didn't use this, I just used a larger bracket to include the rest of the code/ redo the order, but I think this is important to learn so thank you.